# Count number of times a token appears in a document

Tags: c#, .net, nlp, token

I have extracted tokens from the document and inserted them in an array. Now what i want is determining how many times a token appears in the document.

The present algorithm that i have in my mind gets each token and scans the whole array of tokens to find similar tokens. This is as you have guessed not very scalable.

I was looking for some other good algorithm to help me solve this problem.

I have some similar questions on SO but they all assume that the token is provided at compile time.

Comment: If you already have the tokens in the array, can't you just do `array.Length`...?

Comment: Please provide your current code, what your data looks like and what you expect.

Comment: the array has all the tokens, he essentially wants to count duplicates in an array

Comment: Why do you have the c# and java tag ?

Comment: Some kind of hashtable data structure would be the best here. Then you could accomplish this in O(N)

Comment: your question is not very clear. explain it with examples

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Its part of a larger system and right now code is a gigantic mess. Can't post it

Comment: @Cruncher Hash wouldn't able to count the number of tokens i guess.

Comment: @NoOne Sen = "This is SO and this is duplicate". I wan't to find the number of times every token occurs in this sentence efficently.

Comment: Why are you inserting them in an array in the first place? As @Cruncher indicates inserting them in a hashtable (or dictionary with an occurrence count)  would be easier.

Comment: What's the number of tags and the number of tokens? It may be very different if you are looking for natural language words in a long text, or number of DNA bases in a DNA fragment (just to name two very different situations of "counting tokens").

Comment: @Marc-Andre Just wanted to get an idea of algorithm. Language-Agnostic

Comment: @Win Coder actually, yes HashTable CAN count the number of tokens. Kevin lays out the logic.

Comment: @SimoneGianni Yes i am looking for words in a huge amount of text.

Comment: @WinCoder In that case there are Language-Agnostic tags that would better fit your question I think, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Im still confused if he wants to use Java or C# because java doesn't have lambda's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose for the sake of making the example easy that "tokens" are integers. Partition the tokens into equivalence classes using `group by`, and then count the size of each group.

```
var tokens = new[] { 10, 20, 30, 10, 30, 20, 20, 20, 10 };
var grouped = from token in tokens group token by token;
foreach (var grp in grouped)
     Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", grp.Key, grp.Count());
```

Output is:

```
10 3
20 4
30 2
```

Comment: +1 super simple explaination

Comment: will it be scalable for lets say 10 million+ tokens ?

Comment: @WinCoder: How should I know? Try it and see. You're the one who knows what your performance requirements are.

Comment: from token in tokens group token by token;

This sounds too funny

Comment: @Cruncher: Would you prefer this equivalent? `var grouped = tokens.GroupBy(token => token)`

Comment: hmmm it performs query in almost an instant for 100 million tokens. I didn't knew LINQ was so good. Thanks.

Comment: @WinCoder: Did you actually *perform* the query, or just *build* it? Building queries is instantaneous. Actually performing them -- by running it through `foreach`, for example -- can be very time-consuming.

Answer (score 3):

Use a Map/ Hashmap with id of String (which is the token) and Integer (which is the count).

Here is the logic you need.

For every token:

If token exist, increment count by fetching the object by token id and replace the old token 
if token does not exist, add token to map and set the integer value to 1.

Comment: In C#, this would usually be the [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) class

Comment: @Brian agreed! But it was originally java/c#

Comment: Yeah, java was the first tag

Answer (score 1):

#### This answer is for Java

You can use a `HashMap<String,Integer>` (or `SortedMap<String,Integer>`, if you want the result in alphabetical order) where the `key`s are the tokens and the `value` is the count.  For each element in the list, you will need to check if it is already present in the map.  If it is not, you create a new key with value `1`.  If it already is present, you just increment the `value` (count) by 1.

```
HashMap<String,Integer> counts= new HashMap<String,Integer>() ;
for(String e: myTokenList ) {
    if( counts.get(e) == null )
        counts.put(e,1);
    else
        counts.put(e,counts.get(e)+1);
}
```

There is a posible micro-optimization:

```
HashMap<String,Integer> counts= new HashMap<String,Integer>() ;
for(String e: myTokenList ) {
    Integer c= counts.get(e) ;
    if( c == null )
        counts.put(e,1);
    else
        counts.put(e,c+1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to fully understand the question, but that's how you can group values (tokens) and then count the number of times they are present.

```
List<string> tokens = new List<string> { "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "C"};
var tokensCount = tokens.GroupBy(g => g).Select(g => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(g.Key, g.Count()));
// Returns A 3, B 2, C 1
```

Comment: If you don't fully understand the question, then wouldn't a comment first make sense?

Comment: @Cruncher Made a comment, he replied that he cannot post code, actual data or expected results. So that's the closest I can get.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as per a few other suggestions, do not insert the words from your document in an array (unless you have a very good reason for that, which was not yet highlighted in your question).

Instead, insert it into a map/dictionary, like e.g. in the example below (note can be done more efficiently, but this shows each step taken explicitly).

```
var wordCounts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var wordSeparators = new char[] {',', ' ', '\t', ';' /* etc */ };
using (var reader = File.OpenText("allmaywords.txt")
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var words = reader
            .ReadLine() 
            .Split(wordSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(f => f.Trim()).ToList();
        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            if (!wordCounts.ContainsKey(word))
                wordCounts[word] = 1;
            else
                wordCounts[word] = wordCounts[word] + 1;
        } 
    }    
}
```

Now you also have access to all the unique words (or tokens) by:

```
var uniqueTokens = wordCounts.Keys;
```

And you can find out if a token is present:

```
var gotAFoo = wordCounts.ContainsKey("Foo");
```

And how often it is presents:

```
var numbeOfFoosGiven = wordCounts["Foo"];
```